# Where to put a while loop to count till type end in a daemon process?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Where to put a while loop to count till type end in a daemon process? The daemon process should run continuously in the background and log to a file.

> Not sure where I should put this while that loops till I type 0:
> This loop will be recorded after each 5 sec by the daemon process

```
int counter =0;
int i = -1;
while(i!=0){
    printf("type a number: \n);
    scanf("%d", i);
    if (i!=0)
    {
      counter = counter+1;
    }
}
```

> Here is the daemon implementation.
> The daemon process should register the counter in the log.txt after each 5 sec.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp= NULL;
    pid_t process_id = 0;
    pid_t sid = 0;
    // Create child process
    process_id = fork();
    // Indication of fork() failure
    if (process_id < 0)
    {
    printf("fork failed!\n");
    // Return failure in exit status
    exit(1);
    }
    // PARENT PROCESS. Need to kill it.
    if (process_id > 0)
    {
    printf("process_id of child process %d \n", process_id);
    // return success in exit status
    exit(0);
    }
    //unmask the file mode
    umask(0);
    //set new session
    sid = setsid();
    if(sid < 0)
    {
    // Return failure
    exit(1);
    }
    // Change the current working directory to root.
    chdir("/");
    // Close stdin. stdout and stderr
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);
    // Open a log file in write mode.
    fp = fopen ("Log.txt", "w+");
    while (1)
    {
    
    sleep(5);
    fprintf(fp, "Logging info...\n");
```

> this next line should log the counter from the while.

```
    fprintf(fp, counter);
    fflush(fp); 

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Daemon (note 'a before e' — think æ) processes are detached from any terminal — their input is normally `/dev/null` (because you open it and connect it to `stdin`).  You might arrange for `stdout` to go to your log file, and maybe `stderr` too, or you might send them to `/dev/null` too, leaving a separate file stream for logging.  This means you can't and shouldn't expect to type anything as input to a daemon.  It isn't a good idea to just close `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`; code is entitled to expect `stdout` and `stderr` are available, even if the output is invisible; ditto for `stdin`.

Comment: If you've closed STDIN_FILENO, then `scanf` is going to fail.

Comment: It would help if your code was indented in an orthodox style.  I partially fixed it for you, but only partially.

Comment: Let me try to understand because I'm a layman on the subject.
So, if I remove these lines from my code   close(STDIN_FILENO); close(STDOUT_FILENO); close(STDERR_FILENO); The program would work? I am still not sure where to put the loop.